# How to use existing AWS alb in traefik ingress controller

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, traefik-ingress

I installed traefik using helm charts with the below values.yaml
it's not creating ingress and also I am unsure how I should add my existing AWS load balancer name in values.yaml

This is the only snippet I updated in existing traefik helm charts

```
service:
  enabled: true
  ## -- Single service is using `MixedProtocolLBService` feature gate.
  ## -- When set to false, it will create two Service, one for TCP and one for UDP.
  single: true
  type: NodePort
  # -- Additional annotations applied to both TCP and UDP services (e.g. for cloud provider specific config)
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: "test-traefik"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "alb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  # -- Additional annotations for TCP service only
  annotationsTCP: {}
  # -- Additional annotations for UDP service only
  annotationsUDP: {}
  # -- Additional service labels (e.g. for filtering Service by custom labels)
  labels: {}
  # -- Additional entries here will be added to the service spec.
```

Let me know what am I missing ??

Comment: Replace "test-traefik" with the name of your existing AWS ALB
.
Create an Ingress object: You can create an Ingress object to manage Traefik features such as middleware, certificates, and entrypoints

.
Apply the Ingress object: Once applied, an ALB will be created, and you can configure the ALB with the desired settings

Comment: https://traefik.io/blog/eks-clusters-with-traefik-proxy-as-the-ingress-controller/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Above documentation is for nlb. And how ingress can manage traefik features ?